# AttributeError: 'DocsClient' object has no attribute 'GetDocumentListFeed'

Tags: python, google-drive-api, gdata, google-docs-api, gdata-python-client

I'm currently trying to build a Script that interacts with Google's API's, but I keep getting an Attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "service_catalog_automation.py", line 18, in <module>
    feed = client.GetDocumentListFeed()
AttributeError: 'DocsClient' object has no attribute 'GetDocumentListFeed'
```

This is the code I'm trying to use

```
import gdata.gauth
import gdata.docs.client
import sys

def sys_print(text):
    sys.stdout.write(str(text))
    sys.stdout.flush()

CONSUMER_KEY = 'domain.com'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'abcde1234'
requestor_id = 'myuser@domain.com'

client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source='my-script-v1')
client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.TwoLeggedOAuthHmacToken(
    CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, requestor_id)

# Retrieve user's list of Google Docs
feed = client.GetDocumentListFeed()
for entry in feed.entry:
    sys_print(entry.title.text)
    sys_print('\n')
```

I've pulled client.getDocumentListFeed() portion of code from their sample code [here](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/samples/docs/docs_example.py) and have even tried a bare minimum approach using their sample code under the 2LeggedOAuth section [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/oauth#2LeggedOAuth). (I also have tried GetDocList() from that example with the same error)

I have downloaded Google's gdata-python-client to a linux vm's home directory and installed it by running `python setup.py install` and ran the test python `all_tests.py` with no errors.

Any help would be greatly apperciated

Comment: in the first example, they're assigning their client object as the return of `gdata.docs.service.DocsService()`. This would seem to imply that `gd_client` is of type `DocsService`, not `DocsClient`

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, they're assigning their client object as the return of `gdata.docs.service.DocsService()`.

The second example also returns the `client` object as a `DocsService` type:

`client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService(source='yourCompany-YourAppName-v1')`

This would seem to imply that `gd_client` is of type `DocsService`, not `DocsClient`